# PHP loop display MySQL records change id to name column from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing results page that queries a table and shows matching records in a table via a loop like:

```
<table class="WADAResultsTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">clientID:</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $WARRT_AltClass1->getClass(true); ?>">

      <td class="WADAResultsTableCell">
      <?php echo($row_WADAsys_visits['clientID']); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_WADAsys_visits = mysql_fetch_assoc($WADAsys_visits)); ?>
</table>
```

The problem is that the clientID means nothing to the viewer. I created a recordset that performs a join with the table sys_client to get the names.

```
mysql_select_db($database_redcross, $redcross);
$query_idToClient = "SELECT clientLName, clientFName FROM sys_client LEFT JOIN sys_visits USING (clientID)";
$idToClient = mysql_query($query_idToClient, $redcross) or die(mysql_error());
$row_idToClient = mysql_fetch_assoc($idToClient);
$totalRows_idToClient = mysql_num_rows($idToClient);
```

How do I alter the loop to echo the clientFName and clientLName found in that JOIN that matches the pre-existing clientID already echo'd in the loop?

Here is the sys_visits code:

```
$maxRows_WADAsys_visits = 25;
$pageNum_WADAsys_visits = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_WADAsys_visits'])) {
  $pageNum_WADAsys_visits = $_GET['pageNum_WADAsys_visits'];
}
$startRow_WADAsys_visits = $pageNum_WADAsys_visits * $maxRows_WADAsys_visits;

mysql_select_db($database_redcross, $redcross);
$query_WADAsys_visits = "SELECT pid, clientID, address, city, state, zip, latitude, longitude, FROM sys_visits ORDER BY pid ASC";
setQueryBuilderSource($query_WADAsys_visits,$WADbSearch1,false);
$query_limit_WADAsys_visits = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_WADAsys_visits, $startRow_WADAsys_visits, $maxRows_WADAsys_visits);
$WADAsys_visits = mysql_query($query_limit_WADAsys_visits, $redcross) or die(mysql_error());
$row_WADAsys_visits = mysql_fetch_assoc($WADAsys_visits);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_WADAsys_visits'])) {
  $totalRows_WADAsys_visits = $_GET['totalRows_WADAsys_visits'];
} else {
  $all_WADAsys_visits = mysql_query($query_WADAsys_visits);
  $totalRows_WADAsys_visits = mysql_num_rows($all_WADAsys_visits);
}
$totalPages_WADAsys_visits = ceil($totalRows_WADAsys_visits/$maxRows_WADAsys_visits)-1;
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: You need to update `$WADAsys_visits`, not create your own query (i.e. `$query_idToClient`). Do you have access to that code, if so, post it.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I updated the question with the sys_visits code.  I'll check out the deprecation, was not aware.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full schema I can only guess:

```
SELECT pid, clientID, address, city, state, zip, latitude, longitude, clientLName, clientFName FROM sys_visits join sys_client USING( clientID ) ORDER BY pid ASC
```

Then change this line:

```
<td class="WADAResultsTableCell">
  <?php echo($row_WADAsys_visits['clientID']); ?></td>
```

to:

```
<td class="WADAResultsTableCell">    
  <?php echo($row_WADAsys_visits['clientLName']); ?>   
  <?php echo($row_WADAsys_visits['clientFName']); ?></td>
```